# How do I add node_modules folder to existing angular files?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I have a **rookie problem**... You see, I am taking an Angular course, and the teacher is kind enough to leave the project files so I can follow along(picture below), a project which doesn't bring a node_modules folder.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDAk3.png][1]

How exactly do I *install* the node_modules folder for this project so I can run it and follow along? Also, keep in mind I'm working in a Macbook so windows console commands (if any used) won't work. Thanks in advance!

Comment: from the project root (where the package.json file is) run the command `npm install` from your terminal console

Comment: @c_ogoo Thanks man I appreciate it! As I said, it was a rookie problem.

Comment: Its a pleasure, we all have to start from somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first you must install Node.js and NPM on the Mac OS and just run `npm install` command in the root directory of your project (routing-start directory).

You can use the following link to install Node and NPM

https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-mac

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yes, it did! That extra NPM stuff was a good detail (even though I knew abt it) Thank you so much though, I didn't know how this was done if there was already a base project.

Answer (score 6):

So I assume you have the source code without the `node_modules` folder. All you need to do is run `npm install`, it will install all the dependencies for your source code.

It will then create the `node_modules` folder for you automatically and you will be good to go.

So simply run `npm install` from the command line terminal and also make sure you are running it from the folder location of the source code.

Comment: Thank you man, solved it. I didn't know how this was done if there was already a base project.